# Proof: If the dual map $f^*$ is the null map, then $f$ is the null map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces, and let $f:V\to W$ be a linear map. Let $f^*:W^*\to V^*$ be the dual map ($f^*=f^T= f$ transposed). Prove that if $f^*$ is the null map, then $f$ is the null map.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Answer (score 1):

If $f^\ast$ is the null map, then for any $\varphi:W\to K$ we have that $\varphi f:V\to K$ is the null map. This means that ${\rm im \;}f\subseteq\ker \varphi$ for every $\varphi\in W^\ast$. What is $$\bigcap_{\varphi\in  W^\ast}\ker\varphi\;?$$